# How to dynamically seach a mysql table client side with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I know how to search a table with static data. I'd like to modify my script to search the table with dynamic data but I'm unsure how to do this. I'm opened to use Php but since the javascript I have written already works, I'd like help with making the script dynamic.

**script**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("searchData");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**dynamic table**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

     <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Country</th>
        <th>Time Zone</th>
  </tr>
       <?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td data-th="ID"><?=$company['id'];?></a></td>
      <td data-th="Name"><?=$company['title'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Description"><?=$company['description'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Type"><?=$company['type'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Address"><?=$company['address'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Country"><?=$company['country'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Time Zone"><?=$company['timezone'];?></td>
  </tr>

    <?php };?>
    </table>
```

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

Comment: input = document.getElementById("searchData"); i think is: input = document.getElementById("myInput");

Comment: @AndreRodrigues: thanks but the plugin seems deprecated and no longer maintened. I'm trying it right now and it does not work plus the site no longer exists.