# How to keep HTML header from previously designed javascript code

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am not comfortable with Js functions and still learning. I want to use a search function previously designed in order to use dynamic searching, depicted in [How to dynamically seach a mysql table client side with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165589/how-to-dynamically-seach-a-mysql-table-client-side-with-javascript)

As I poorly understand, I can see that this delivers what we search in all columns. But when I try to implement [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table) with the function in the other link, i can see that the original HTML header disappears.

Is there a way to modify this code or any other way in order to keep the HTML header?

```
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables 
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, occurrence;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        occurrence = false; // Only reset to false once per row.
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for(var j=0; j< td.length; j++){                
            currentTd = td[j];
            if (currentTd ) {
                if (currentTd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    occurrence = true;
                } 
            }
        }
        if(!occurrence){
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        } 
    }
}
```

and the HTML code, from the link

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please clearly define what you are trying to accomplish and what the issue is. 'Dynamic searching' inst really a thing and entirely open to interpretation -- what headers are you referring to? HTTP headers?

Comment: @Crayons thank you for your reply. I have edited the question. And yes, the HTML headers disappear and I would like to know why and how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a leap here but sounds like in your html table the header is actually the first  tag. So the js code you wrote seems to be including that in it's logic.

Change this line

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question to include the HTML you are using as its pretty important. Without seeing it, im going to guess because your headers live within a row of the table itself. `<tr></tr>`

My advice, would be to separate the data into `<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>` first and then only reference the rows within `<tbody>`.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>header 1</td>
            <td>header 2</td>
            <td>header 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>row 1 - cell 1</td>
            <td>row 1 - cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1 - cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 2 - cell 1</td>
            <td>row 2 - cell 2</td>
            <td>row 2 - cell 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 3 - cell 1</td>
            <td>row 3 - cell 2</td>
            <td>row 3 - cell 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then do something like:

```
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
body = table.find('tbody');
tr = body.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Comment: I have put a link to demonstrate the code i'm trying to implement, but with the function described above. I have tried what you have done and still I can't make it work